# IIS 10.0 http 500 error reading .txt after kb5001402 and 1347

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-10, windows-update

We have 3 ASP.NET 4.5 websites set up in IIS 10.0, windows 2016,  all on port 443 using Host Headers to direct to correct site. The sites are on 2 servers with an NLB in front, the NLB pings each site looking for a status.txt at the root of each site folder to know if the site is active.

After the windows updates kb5001402 and 1347 on april 27th, the NLB can no longer read the status.txt files,  IIS is returning a http 500 error. There is nothing in the event logs or the IIS logs except the http 500.

I'm at a bit of a loss where to look next or how to fix this, any thoughts or ideas?

Additional Info: To narrow things down, I turned off the second server removed all the sites but one and removed the host header, so now I have one site on one server on port 443. Using the server name to bypass the NLB I can access .aspx pages, but the .txt and .png files do not load. So for some reason IIS will not serve the .txt or .png after the patches

Edit and Answer - It turned out the service account the app pool was running under had been removed from the required "permission" set of the certificate the site was running under. No idea how this happen or if was even related to the kb.

Comment: If there is no error message, it is difficult to find the problem, you can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view the detailed error message. and usually, the problem of unable to read files is caused by permission problems, so you can try to check the permissions in the file or folder.

Answer (score 2):

Those KBs have been installed this morning on my system and I had a similar issue in an app where PNGs were not displaying anymore.

In my case, it turned to be a security problem: A website running with anonymous authentication under the App Pool identity. And, this morning, the authentication was set to `IUSR`. Which led to the PNG not being shown (due to access being denied, I suppose). After setting authentication back to 'app pool identity', the problem was solved.

I didn't find anything in the KB which can explain this. I presume that the txt file should be 'anonymous' to be read from a NLB.

Have you already checked that nothing has changed around the authentication on you system?